# How to override Laravel 8 authentification function

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream, laravel-fortify

I am building an application using (laravel 8,Jetstream, Fortify), this how the users table looks like

```
id
name
email
tag
```

i need to check if the tag field is empty for a specific user when that user authenticate successfully, if it's empty i need to assign a variable to it from the link like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login?tag=100
```

I need to know where exactly can I find the function so I can edit the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your custom logic for authentication with Jetstream by  using `Jetstream::authenticateUsing()` method in the `boot()` method of the `app/Providers/JetstreamServiceProvider.php`

```php
//Directly taken from the Jetstream docs
Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    if ($user &&
        Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        return $user;
    }
});
```

Jetstream docs: https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/features/authentication.html#customizing-the-authentication-process